# How to ignore characters and read only integers in a c file

Tags: c

I have a file and using fscanf i want to read only the integers and ignore the characters if any.

Like the file would be:

1
2
a
5
c
6

(i.e on each line there would ne only a single number or character... and i want to ignore lines with character)
so i need to read only the integer values.

Does any body know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Read each line. Tokenize. Attempt to parse. Skip on error. The full interface of `strtol()` should let you do all this in one wash.

Comment: What do you have so far? Where does it fail? Do you get an error? Also, should the first value become 1 or 12?

Comment: Here's a hint: the `scanf` specifier `"%*[^0123456789]"` will read all characters that aren't digits and throw them away.  But as other answers have indicated, the `scanf()` family probably isn't he best way to approach this - especially if you need to be able to read negative numbers and handle a `'-'` character that's not properly associated with a number.

Comment: Here is what i am doingFILE *fp;
fp = fopen (argv[2], "r");
if (fp==NULL)
{
puts ("\n cannot read the file");
return 0;
}

count =0;
int no_frames,temp,i;
size=argv[1];
fscanf(fp, "%d", &temp);

while (!feof(fp))
{
pages[count++]=temp;
//fscanf(fp,"%d", &temp);
fscanf(fp, "%d", &temp);
}
fclose(fp);
size=atoi(argv[1]);
FIFO();
LRU();
How to implement in this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Regular expressions.

While reading, check with a regex filter, then use conditional statement. If regex is satisfied (i.e. input is an integer). then complete the reading process, else move to next input.

Comment: A regex library for rather simple string processing would be way overkill, especially in C where it's not a native library.

Comment: Didn't think about it. Still it will be simpler, and more error proof than to write a complete function like @Jason Lark wrote below. If a guy is using IO in c, he should be able to learn a regex operation as simple as this one require.

Comment: It would be much, much easier and faster to just read the string, tokenize it, then try to parse each item as an integer.  Regexp is *way* overkill for this.  It would produce a slower, bigger application that would be more complex for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Are the numbers all single-digit? In that case, you could read character by character with getc, use isdigit to see if it is a digit, and if so process it.

Can the numbers have more than one digit? In that case, you could use something similiar, but when you get to a digit, put it back in the stream with ungetc, and read the number with fscanf(..., "%d", ....).

I know that the usual advice is to read line by line with fgets and then parse the data from that line, and I agree that with input directly from the user this is probably the best way. But for reading a file like this I think it is overkill, and simpler solutions can, and often should, be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [isnum](http://man.cx/isdigit) to check the individual strings, or just call [strtol](http://man.cx/strtol)/atoi and check if errno was set to EINVAL.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol

Comment: **scanf("%d%*c",&n);** will read integers, and store then in **n**, but skip over characters.

Comment: Reading into a buffer with **fgets();**, then using **sscanf();** is safer.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to proceed char-by-char to find each integer. Handle negative numbers (proceeded by a '-') with a negative flag.

```
//pseudo-code
int negative = 0;
int curdigit = 0;
char c = '\0';
while((c = getchar())) //pseudo-function, get the next character from the stream (i.e fgetc)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        curdigit = (c - '0');
        if (negative)
            curdigit *= -1; //can just do this bitwise, but im lazy.
        //do something with the current digit.
        negative = 0; //negative cannot persist for more than 1 iteration.
    }
    else if (c == '-')
    {
        negative = 1;
    }   
    else { negative = 0; }
}
```